# update $scope info from another controller

Tags: angularjs

How can i make the testservice factory return the result from the post request?, or make the app, factory update some `$scope` details thats within the `overallcontroller` ?

how can i update information within the `overallcontroller` from another controller?

```
app.factory('testservice', ['$http', 'auth', function($http, auth) {

var o = {
    posts : []
};

o.test = function() {
  return $http.post('/poster', null, {
    headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
  }).success(function(data){
   console.log(Data);


  });
};  



return o;
```

}]);

```
    app.controller('overallController', ['$scope', 'posts', 'testservice', 'auth','$interval',
function($scope, posts, testservice,  auth, $interval) {

    $scope.data = {cash:"12879999",location:"test2",gang:"None","username":"test",
    xp: 1290,
    health: 100,
    wanted: 30,
    energy: 90};


    var databackground = function() {
          console.log("logging...");
          var t = testservice.test;
          console.log(t);


    }

    databackground();
             $interval(databackground, 30000);




}]);
```

**example html**

```
   <div class="main" ng-controller="overallController">
   <section class="sides left" style="background:blue; height:100px;">
    <ul>
      <li ng-hide="isLoggedIn()"><a href="/#/login">Logg inn</a></li>

    </ul>
   </section>
<div ng-controller"othercontroller">
 // call made from some code here
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your service to

```
o.test = function() {
  return $http.post('/poster', null, {
    headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
  }).then(function(response){
    return response.data;
  });
};
```

And in your controller, do **call** the service, and get the results back in the promise:

```
testservice.test().then(function(data) {
  $scope.data = data;
});
```

Read more about how to use promises [here](http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/)

Comment: if this is called in MainCtrl controller, and overallcontroller holds the $scope.data info, how can i transfer the result into that overallcontroller while calling it in mainctrl?

Comment: If it's overallcontroller that needs this data, why do you put that code in MainCtrl in the first place, and not in overallcontroller?

Comment: because i feel like i should call for the updated data after some special enteries that is done within the mainctrl scope.  is it better to use one controller instead of two on a page?

Comment: It depends. Your controller can emit and listen to events. Read the $scope documentation for more information.

Comment: may we chat please?

Answer (score 0):

You return the promise from your service, you would listen for that to resovle and get hold of your data.

Using `$rootScope` is heavy handed approach and should be used as a last resort. Services and event are preferable.

```
var databackground = function() {
  console.log("logging...");
  testservice.test()
    .then(function (res) {
        console.log(res.data); //Here is your data
    });
}
```

---

EDIT: Your service should change slightly also. Firstly `.success` and `.error` are deprecated. Use `.then` and `.catch` instead.

If you wish to just return data out of your service just do:

```
o.test = function() {
  return $http.post('/poster', null, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + auth.getToken()
    }
  });
};
```

However if you want to transform the data in your service you can but ensure your return it or your controller wont get anything:

```
o.test = function() {
  return $http.post('/poster', null, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + auth.getToken()
    }
  })
  .then(function (res) {
    res.data.test = 'lol';

    return res;
  })
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Try referencing $rootScope instead of $scope.

This will allow controllers and factories to interact with each other.

Comment: could you make an example?